# Disable VPN connection using pfctl in macos

Tags: networking, mac

I want to disable any traffic which passes through VPN connections. I just want it to go through my local internet and a specific DNS. I figured out the specific DNS part but can't seem to find any solutions for creating pf rules which disables VPN connections.

So far this is what I have

```
block all

# specific dns usage
pass out proto {tcp, udp} from any to 8.8.8.8 port 53 keep state
pass out proto {tcp, udp} from any to 8.8.4.4 port 53 keep state

# allow traffic through local ip - doesn't work
pass on en0 proto {tcp, udp} from any to 192.168.50.67 port {80, 443}
```

Is it even possible to disable VPN connections using pfctl in macOS Ventura?

Comment: Why can't you just quit the VPN? Company Mac?

Comment: I want to block vpn running on MAC due to some reasons.